# In Tableau, Is it possible to give Column number in Column Shelf

Tags: tableau-api

I'm using Tableau. So, instead of giving the **[Column_name]**, Is it possible to give **[Column_number]** in column shelf?
- Hariharasudhan. R.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: No. (useless characters that SO makes me type because No is too short)

Answer (score 1):

No -- for good reason.

Think of the data source as a template for a potential SQL (or MDX or TQL) query; specifying tables, joins, unions and possibly some where/having clauses for data source filters.

The actual SQL generated for any particular view will be an (optimized) query that only selects columns that are actually needed for that particular view, adds where/having clauses based on the filters being used etc.

So a column doesn't have a fixed number. The same column may be the first field selected in one situation, the last field in another situation, and left off completely in another.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to change the name of column shelf:**

Create a duplicate of variable and change original with duplicates and assign name as your wish by right-click on Edit Aliases and change as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to **Data Source**
2. On the middle right corner check on **Show aliases**
3. Go to column and right click on it. Go to **Rename**

[image]